# Interesting task on Poisson process

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Child is playing computer game. The moments of appearance of enemies  forms poisson point process with $\lambda =400 $ enemies per hour. Child kills an enemy with probability $\frac{1}{4}$ (he do it instantly). In order to pass the level he needs kill $100$ enemies . I need to find the distribution of time of passing level. So actually I don’t know how attempt this problem.

Comment: I assume "he needs not kill 100 enemies" should say "he needs to kill 100 enemies."

Comment: (i) if the child kills an enemy with probability one, do you know how to find the distribution of time until passing level?  (ii) do you know about poisson splitting?

Comment: Actually I don’t know about poisson splitting

Comment: And I have no idea about your first hint

Comment: for (i), one way or another you need to learn that the time until the kth arrival in a Poisson process is given by an Erlang (special case of Gamma) distribution.  This is completely standard and taught in any introduction to Poisson processes that I know of.  It really is just a convolution of $k$ iid exponential r.v.'s.

Comment: So I guess the second hint is connected with $p \neq 1$ case?

Comment: And I need two variables $X$ - number of enemies which have been killed and $Y$ - number of enemies which are still alive? I think I can find PMFs of them and PMF of joint. But I can’t realize how It could be helpful in deriving the distribution of time

Comment: yes the second hint uses special properties of Poisson processes so that you get a very nice answer -- nothing gruesome with joint PMFs... there's actually a very nice and short chapter on Poisson processes in the free book by Blitzstein and Hwang (they call poisson splitting, "poisson thinning" but same thing).  The home site is here:  https://projects.iq.harvard.edu/stat110/home